# Como realizar operações matemáticas através de variáveis

Tags: python

Estou tentando escrever um pequeno algoritmo que calcule o valor de décimo terceiro salário do usuário. O passo a passo é:

1. inserir salário base
2. inserir quantos meses trabalhou
3. salário base/12 * meses trabalhados

O código está assim:

```
salarioBase = int(input('Digite o valor de salário mensal: '))

mesesTrabalhados = int(input('Digite quantos meses trabalhou: '))

proporcional: salarioBase/12* mesesTrabalhados:
```

Porém na variável `proporcional` está havendo um erro de sintaxe e eu não sei como fazer certo para que eu possa rodar esse resultado e escrever `print(proporcional 'Esse é o valor de 13º')`.

Comment: Você usou : para atribuir na última linha e deixou outro : no final da linha. Nenhum desses é uma sintaxe válida nesse contexto.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

manda a mensagem de erro por gentileza !

mas a principio tente isso

```
salario = int(input('informe o seu salário'))
meses_trabalhados = int(input('meses trabalhados'))
print((salario/12)*meses_trabalhados)
```

Comment: File "projeto4.py", line 3
    proporcional: salarioBase/12* mesesTrabalhados:
                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


parece que o erro está nos : que coloquei no final, mas coloquei eles pra poder escrever print embaixo, deu pra entender?

Comment: jovem, tenta por meio desse código que mandei acima e da um feedback depois !

Comment: deu certo, valeu demais!!!

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você usou `:` para fazer uma atribuição. Em Python, o token correto para fazer isto é `=`. O modo correto de escrever a última linha seria este:

```
proporcional = salarioBase/12 * mesesTrabalhados
```